# How do I Pass Values from One Form to Another?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have this form:

```
<form name="summaryform">
      <select name="category" id="category" style="width:500px;">
        <option value="">Choose category...</option>
        <option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
        <option value="AppleScript">AppleScript</option>
        <option value="Asp">Asp</option>
        <option value="BASIC">BASIC</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
        <option value="C++">C++</option>
        <option value="Clojure">Clojure</option>
        <option value="COBOL">COBOL</option>
        <option value="ColdFusion">ColdFusion</option>
        <option value="Erlang">Erlang</option>
        <option value="Fortran">Fortran</option>
        <option value="Groovy">Groovy</option>
      </select><br>
      <select name="subcategory" id="subcategory" style="width:500px;">
        <option value="">Choose sub category...</option>
        <option value="Haskell">Haskell</option>
        <option value="Java">Java</option>
        <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
        <option value="Lisp">Lisp</option>
        <option value="Perl">Perl</option>
        <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
        <option value="Python">Python</option>
        <option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
        <option value="Scala">Scala</option>
        <option value="Scheme">Scheme</option>
      </select><br>
  <input type="text" name="comments" id="comments" value="  Enter request comments..." onfocus="clearText(this)" onblur="restoreText(this)" style="width:493px;color:#999;font-size:9pt;height:20px;">
```

On the form above, I have two dropdowns (name="categoryId" and "subcategoryid") and one textboxt (name="comments")

How do I pass the values from this form to another form?

Let's say below is the form I want to pass the values to:

```
  <div>
    <p>
      <form name="summaryform" method='POST' action='process.php'>
      <div style="font-size:12pt;">
       value from one dropdown
       value from the other dropdown
       value from textbox
      </form>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: forms are in one page, or from first submitting to second ?

Comment: Why you need to send one form values to another form ?

Comment: if the two forms are in different pages, you should specify to the first one a **method** and, eventually, an **action**, unless it acts on the same page. If the two forms are on the same page, then the second form can't have any value until the first one hasn't been set

Comment: @VaheShadunts, and other helpers, forms are in one page.

They asked me to do it that way so they can review data first before they either edit or submit to the db.

Comment: you want to echo the values selected, or show whole select list, only selected the value ?

Comment: @Chidi Okeh: if the forms are in the same page, then, you shouldn't show the second one if the first one hasn't been set. The alternative solution, if you DON'T want to reload the page after the first form has been set, is using AJAX and PHP together. Update: check zsaat14's solution below, the jQuery method is probably what you're looking for: once the first form has been submitted, through jQuery, it compiles the second one and submit it. That's probably what you're looking for, right?

Comment: Use Jquery `serializeArray()` or `serialize()` function...

Comment: instead of using two forms, you could use a popup to show what has been entered and then users clicks 'OK' to submit or 'Cancel' to edit further.

Comment: @iroegbu, nice idea. can you please show some example?

Comment: It won't pass as an answer to your question though... `onsubmit="return showPopUp();"` then write a js function `showPopUp()` that shows the popup and returns true of false depending on user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jQuery Method**

If the forms are on the same page, you can use jQuery to get the values and write to the div:

```
var content = $('#category').val()+'<br>'+$('#subcategory').val()+'<br>'+$('#comments').val();
$('#div-to-write-to').html(content);
```

**PHP Method**

If the forms are on different pages, you will need to use PHP and the $_POST[] variable to pass the values you are looking for.

NOTE: for this method to work the page being POSTed to MUST be PHP.  You will also need to add an action and method in the first form to POST to the second form.

This would be the code in the form on the page being POSTed to:

```
<?php echo $_POST['category'].'<br>'.$_POST['subcategory'].'<br>'.$_POST['comments']; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the codes. Sorry for stupid question but how do they get displayed on the sumamry form for review if I was to use jquery?

Comment: That is what the `$('#div-to-write-to').html(content);` is for.  It writes the content created in the previous line to the div.  Both lines need to go in a `<script></script>` tag after the second form.  You will need to add some event listeners if you want to have the values updated after the first form is filled out.

Comment: @chidiokeh. You will need to replace div-to-write-to with the id of the div you want to write to.  Your original code does not show an id, so you may need to add one.

Comment: I did and I called it preview, that is <div id="preview">

This is only useful if I am using the jquery which I tried but it only shows values if the values hardcoded. It doesn't since it is dynamically populated.

Also, what I meant with the last post is that I was trying php and it isn't showing anything either.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh PHP will not work on a single page.  You will need to wrap the jQuery in this for it to call after the first form is submitted:     `$("#summaryForm").bind('submit',function(e) {/*the earlier code here*/});`

Comment: the first form does not submit. That's what I have been trying to say.

It is more like slider or accordion.

You select the values from two dropdowns and you enter value into textbox and then click the next menu or accordion.

The expectation is that the values are displayed there when you get to it.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh Ok, then just fire the jQuery when the next menu is clicked.  `$("#accordion-id").click(function() {/*the earlier code here*/});`.

Comment: You are great, man!

I don't know you but I love you, dude.

It is almost working.

Only thing is that it returns the id instead of the text.

For instance, if if is B40004, and the text is Grading the next generation of geeks, we would like to see it return the text.

Any ideas how to fix? That will do the trick really.
THanks so much

Comment: @ChidiOkeh See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/At8Kn/3/ It is a completely working example using your code.

Answer (score 0):

A value can be passed between forms using the POST and GET methods. The first form (Which is sending the values) does not have this defined, so modify the first form to this -

```
<form name="summaryform" method='POST' action='process.php'>
```

Then, in process.php, put the following php code -

```
$dropdown_first = $_POST['category'];
$dropdown_second= $_POST['subcategory'];
$comment = $_POST['comments'];
```

After that, you can just use the variables as you see fit!

Comment: And what if it is in the same page? Also, I think if you don't specify a method it is by default GET.

Comment: Yes, GET is the default.  It does not need to be defined unless you intend to use POST.

Comment: @zsaat14, for some reason, I am not seeing the values in another form.

Please remember that the forms are all on SAME page.

Comment: If the forms are in the same page, action can be changed from process.php to whatever the page name is..

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want just print the selected values from first form @zsaa14's
   answer is good
2. If you want to print whole select list, **autoselected** your value, **heres a code**.

`foreach($categories as $category) {`

`$selected = $category['name'] === $_POST['category'] ? 'selected="selected"' : '';`

`echo " <option value="{$category['name']}" {$selected}>{$category['name']}</option>" ;`

`}`

> **NOTE:** the variable names and keys are for example, use Yours. This is only fragment of code.

Comment: my apologizes for non pretty codeview in answer, but editor wasn't work as it was, and I cant mark the whole code.

Answer (score -2):

You can use post data fields to send the values to the next form

Comment: That's not what he wants. Hidden fields are not needed if the form needs to be shown

Comment: So when he will submit the one form he will get the post and then he can use the posted values in the as the values for the new form fields .Apologies i used the hidden field

Comment: The alternative way could be using Jquery and as soon as someone select the value use onchange event to get the data and add to the second form